# How do I add an electrical switch to a series of lights from an additional doorway?

Tags: switch

My basement shop has been fully wired to operate by one power switch.  I would like to add another switch to power up the shop by entering from another door.

Answer (score 0):

Ahh, the miracles of modern science. You can control your light from multiple locations **and you don't even have to run any additional wiring**.

[wireless 3-way switching, no power needed NOT EVEN BATTERIES!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3KeGc5cPX8o&feature=youtu.be)

Comment: This is a good answer, you should add it to the question that this is a duplicate of.